# Share `user` data in all the application after authentification with vue3 and amplify

Tags: authentication, vuejs3, amazon-cognito, amplifyjs

Context: *Vue 3*, *Quasar*, *Amplify*, *Cognito*, first vue, quasar and amplify project

How may I make the **`user`** from the authenticator slot available to **`TheUserHeader`** and all the other pages used by `router-view`? **Actually, I want the `user` variable to be available anywhere in the application.**

```html
// layout/UserLayout.vue
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <TheUserHeader />

    <q-page-container>
      <authenticator variation="modal" :login-mechanisms="['username']"
        :sign-up-attributes="['email', 'locale', 'updated_at']">
        <template v-slot="{ user }">
          <h3>Hello {{ user.username }}!</h3>

          <router-view />   // <= Meaningful Page Contect
        </template>
      </authenticator>
    </q-page-container>

    <TheFooter />
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

An approach seem to be using injection (`provide`), but I do not know how to pass the v-slot value of `user` as an argument to `provide()`.

Is there any "best practice"?